# How to call a method inside another method Asynchronously in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, java-8

I have a "persistLogin" method call inside a "login" method but I'd like to get the response of the login method before the "persistLogin" method call executes. My question is:
HOW DO I CALL THE "PERSITLOGIN" METHOD AFTER THE "LOGIN" METHOD? Thank you.

NB: persitLogin method persists a user after they have already loggedin.
Login method: does validations and actually logs in a customer.
persistLogin method in inside login method.

The code is below:

```
public LoginEventResponse Login(EventV2<LoginEventDetails> event) {
    CustomerV2 customerV2 = null;
    if (customerV2 == null)  {
        throw new ApiException("Customer with federated id : " + event.getFederatedId() + " not found");
    }

    ***EventEntity entity = eventPersistenceService.persistLogin(customerV2, event);***
    return eventMapper.mapToLoginEventResponseV2(entity, customerV2);
}
```

Comment: Not clear. `entity` is returned by `persistLogin` and needed in return from `Login`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [executorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and submit the persistence call as a lambda... it sounds like you mostly want to ignore the result (and assume it just worked).
A more robust solution would be to enqueue a message for subsequent processing. This would require a message handling system... [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/), [message queue](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/intro-java-message-service.html), something, that you could submit messages to and register handlers for... but it would make the semantics for failed calls clear and straightforward to handle.